# Библиотеки и фреймворки javascript в проектах ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Хочу углубиться в проекты ASP.NET. Какие бесплатные библиотеки javascript рекомендуете использовать ? Запросы такие: регулярные обновления, нормальная техподдержка, приличный функционал.

Comment: могу посоветовать не углубляться, потом не отмоетесь :)

ну и вопрос "посоветуйте библиотеку"

[вот классная либа](http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/) :) довольны ?

Comment: А как же под веб писать без фреймворков и библиотек ?

Comment: @Alex9 наверное, все же имеет смысл искать инструменты под конкретные нужды, а не просто абстрактные "бесплатные библиотеки javascript"

Comment: >могу посоветовать не углубляться, потом не отмоетесь :)

@eicto извините, откуда такое предубеждение?

Comment: >А как же под веб писать без фреймворков и библиотек ?

Как-как... Берём CGI, берём C и пишем. При этом желательно не пользоваться стандартной библиотекой C, а написать свою (ибо стандартная библиотека тоже может считаться фреймворком). А ещё лучше писать на ассемблере, желательно под процессор, собранный на коленке из добытого вручную кремния.

Comment: @DreamChild да как-то не верю я им, они постоянно прокидывают своих разработчиков обратно несовместимыми стандартами. (всего-то десять лет назад было)

Comment: @eicto А Вы не застряли в прошлом веке? (я просто не в курсе текущей ситуации, sorry, но подозреваю, что амбиции MS уже существенно усохли)

Comment: Интересуют в первую очередь библиотеки для SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ASP.NET, то [KnockoutJS](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template) например.

Выбор огромен:

- [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.com/)
- [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)
- [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)
- и многие [другие](http://todomvc.com/)